# How can I install pdal in python in a dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, apt-get

I have my own dockerfile, which creates an image with python with gdal and several other packages:

```
FROM geodata/gdal:2.1.2

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
       build-essential \
       gfortran \
       libatlas-base-dev \
       python-pip \
       python-dev \
       libxft-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev

RUN apt-get install -y python-tk
RUN pip install \
    numpy \
    matplotlib \
    scipy \
    click \
    Pillow \
    scikit-image \
    Cython \
    packaging
RUN apt-get install -y liblas-c3
RUN apt-get install pdal
RUN pip install liblas
RUN pip install laspy
RUN pip install pdal


WORKDIR /data
VOLUME /data
```

I am simply trying to install pdal, note the two lines in the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install pdal
RUN pip install pdal
```

but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to build the image, it just writes the error message:

```
Step 9 : RUN apt-get install pdal
 ---> Running in b7d7f128024e
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package pdal
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install pdal' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I can't seem to figure out how to add pdal to an image, and their hp https://www.pdal.io/quickstart.html only states how to download docker and get pdal as a seperate image, which is not so helpfull, since I need it in my own image along with all the other python packages! How can this be done??

Comment: Modify your Dockerfile in order to have only one RUN, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/  for example  you can group 2 lines with `RUN apt-get install pdal \ && pip install pdal` you have a problem, as long as apt-get install does not find pdal

Comment: did you try what they say on the link you provided `docker run -v /c/Users/hobu:/data pdal/pdal:1.5 pdal info /data/autzen.laz -p 0
`?

Comment: I tried writing them in one RUN, but I just get the error: E: Unable to locate package pdal   E: Unable to locate package. As stated in the question I can't just use the pdal/pdal:1.5 image, because it doesn't have the other python packages I need, and I can't add my own python scripts either. This is why I made my own dockerfile.

Comment: are you sure using `FROM geodata/gdal:2.1.2
` implies you have this package?

Comment: may be you should install git, then `git clone https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL.git pdal`and so, see an example of a Dockerfile installing from source, building and cleaning https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs_git/

Comment: `FROM geodata/gdal:2.1.2` does not imply that I already have pdal. I am asking how to install pdal. Liblas is also installed in the dockerfile, and I just want to do the same thing for pdal.

Comment: from your link 
RPMs

RPMs for PDAL are available at https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/neteler/pdal/
Debian

Debian packages are now available on Debian Unstable.

Comment: @user2915097 I don't know what this means, I have never used RPM before. If I just copy/paste the code given in the link I just get "dnf: not found". What exactly am I supposed to write in the dockerfile?

Comment: Dnf is for recent versions of Fedora/RedHat only

Comment: @user2915097 I still don't understand, what I am supposed to write in my dockerfile!